How to check input/output data for shaders in Renderdoc?
How can I check whether my vertex and pixel shaders' input and output have data in Renderdoc?
I have a problem with my pixel shader when I try to include input color. I get a black screen. When I include 1.0f instead, it kind of works (it draws the shape in white)
Texture2D texture1;
//Texture2D texture2 : register(t1);
//Texture2D texture3 : register(t2);
//Texture2D texture4 : register(t3);

SamplerState Sampler;

struct PixelShaderInput
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float3 normal : normal;
    float2 UV : UV;
    float4 WorldPosition : WorldPosition;
};


struct PixelShadeOutput
{
    float4 Color : SV_TARGET0; //Diffuse
    float4 normal : SV_TARGET1;
    float4 position : SV_TARGET2;
    //float4 WorldPosition : SV_TARGET3;
};

PixelShadeOutput main(PixelShaderInput input) : SV_TARGET
{
    PixelShadeOutput output;
    float4 TextureColor = texture1.Sample(Sampler, input.UV);
    output.Color = 1.0f;
    output.normal = float4(input.normal, 1.0f);
    output.position = input.WorldPosition;
    
    return output;
}


For Vertex Shader, you can see the input and output in the Mesh Viewer window.
You will have two tabs, VS input and VS output.
However, you will have to select the correct event on the Event Browser window where your shader is called (glDrawArrays in my case)
I have no idea for other shaders for pixel or fragment, and I'm also interested knowing how. (I just discovered RenderDoc)
